# How to set dynamic id for each td in Html table using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I set id for each td in the html table? For more information what I need is that each created new field will have in a unique Id for example: first tr will have three  with id-s :edit_mailing_dates_delivery_input_2; edit_mailing_dates_deadline_input_2; edit_mailing_dates_release_input_2;

the second new  will have : edit_mailing_dates_delivery_input_2_1; edit_mailing_dates_deadline_input_2_1; edit_mailing_dates_release_input_2_1; and so on.

```js
`enter code here`const seasonChart = document.getElementsByClassName('MailingSeason')[0];
`enter code here`const createSeason = document.getElementById('createNewSeason');

createSeason.addEventListener('click', editMailingDates());

function editMailingDates() {
  let editMailingDatesFrame = document.createElement('div');
  let editMailingDatesOuter = document.createElement('div');
  let editMailingDatesHeader = document.createElement('div');
  let editMailingDatesHeaderText = document.createElement('h6');
  let editMailingDatesBody = document.createElement('div');
  let editmailingdatesTable = document.createElement('table');
  let editMailingDatesTableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  let editMailingDatesRow = document.createElement('tr');
  let editMailingDatesDeadlineFrame = document.createElement('th');
  let editMailingDatesReleaseFrame = document.createElement('th');
  let editMailingDatesdeliveryFrame = document.createElement('th');
  let editMailingDatesEditFrame = document.createElement('th');
  let editMailingDatesDeleteFrame = document.createElement('th');
  let editMailingDatesDeadlineHeader = document.createElement('h5');
  let editMailingDatesReleaseHeader = document.createElement('h5');
  let editMailingDatesDeliveryHeader = document.createElement('h5');
  let editMailingDatesEditFrameHeader = document.createElement('h5');
  let editMailingDatesDeleteFrameHeader = document.createElement('h5');
  let editMailingDatesFooter = document.createElement('div');
  let editMailingDatesSaveButton = document.createElement('button');
  let editMailingDatesPrevButton = document.createElement('button');
  let editMailingDatesAddNewButton = document.createElement('button');
  let editMailingDatesAddNewButtonSave = document.createElement('button');

  let editMailingDatesAddNewButtonFrame = document.createElement('div');
  let editMailingDatesBodyOuter = document.createElement('div');


  editMailingDatesFrame.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_frame');
  editMailingDatesOuter.setAttribute('class', 'new_season_options_outer');
  editMailingDatesHeader.setAttribute('class', 'new_season_header');
  editMailingDatesBody.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_body');
  editMailingDatesBodyOuter.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_body_inner');
  editMailingDatesDeadlineFrame.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_deadline_frame');
  editMailingDatesReleaseFrame.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_release_frame');
  editMailingDatesdeliveryFrame.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_delivery_frame');
  editMailingDatesFooter.setAttribute('class', 'manage_products_footer');
  editMailingDatesPrevButton.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_prev_button');
  editMailingDatesAddNewButton.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_add_new_button');
  editMailingDatesAddNewButtonSave.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_add_new_button_save');
  editMailingDatesTableBody.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_table_body');
  editMailingDatesAddNewButtonFrame.setAttribute('class', 'buttons_frame');

  editMailingDatesHeaderText.textContent = "Termine andern / change dates";
  editMailingDatesDeadlineHeader.textContent = "Bestellfrist";
  editMailingDatesReleaseHeader.textContent = "Druckfreigabe bis";
  editMailingDatesDeliveryHeader.textContent = "Anlieferung";
  editMailingDatesEditFrameHeader.textContent = "Edit";
  editMailingDatesDeleteFrameHeader.textContent = "Delete";
  editMailingDatesSaveButton.textContent = "Save";
  editMailingDatesPrevButton.textContent = "Go Back";
  editMailingDatesAddNewButton.textContent = "+";
  editMailingDatesAddNewButtonSave.textContent = "Update";


  seasonChart.appendChild(editMailingDatesFrame);
  editMailingDatesFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesOuter);
  editMailingDatesOuter.appendChild(editMailingDatesHeader);
  editMailingDatesHeader.appendChild(editMailingDatesHeaderText);
  editMailingDatesOuter.appendChild(editMailingDatesBodyOuter);
  editMailingDatesBodyOuter.appendChild(editMailingDatesBody);
  editmailingdatesTable.appendChild(editMailingDatesRow);
  editMailingDatesBody.appendChild(editmailingdatesTable);
  editMailingDatesRow.appendChild(editMailingDatesDeadlineFrame);
  editMailingDatesRow.appendChild(editMailingDatesReleaseFrame);
  editMailingDatesRow.appendChild(editMailingDatesdeliveryFrame);
  editMailingDatesRow.appendChild(editMailingDatesEditFrame);
  editMailingDatesRow.appendChild(editMailingDatesDeleteFrame);
  editMailingDatesEditFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesEditFrameHeader);
  editMailingDatesDeleteFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesDeleteFrameHeader);


  editMailingDatesBodyOuter.appendChild(editMailingDatesAddNewButtonFrame);
  editMailingDatesAddNewButtonFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesAddNewButton);
  editMailingDatesAddNewButtonFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesAddNewButtonSave);
  editMailingDatesDeadlineFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesDeadlineHeader);
  editMailingDatesReleaseFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesReleaseHeader);
  editMailingDatesdeliveryFrame.appendChild(editMailingDatesDeliveryHeader);
  editmailingdatesTable.appendChild(editMailingDatesTableBody);
  editMailingDatesOuter.appendChild(editMailingDatesFooter);
  editMailingDatesFooter.appendChild(editMailingDatesPrevButton);
  editMailingDatesFooter.appendChild(editMailingDatesSaveButton);



}


const createNewDateInputFields = document.getElementById('edit_mailing_dates_add_new_button');
const createNewCostsInputFields = document.getElementById('edit_printing_costs_add_inputs_button');



createNewDateInputFields.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const deadlineFrame = document.getElementById('edit_mailing_dates_table_body');
  const datesInputFieldsFrame = document.createElement('tr');
  const additonalInput1Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput2Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput3Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  const additonalInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  const additonalInput3 = document.createElement('input');

  datesInputFieldsFrame.setAttribute('id', 'dates_input_fields_frame');
  additonalInput1.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_delivery_input_2')

  additonalInput2.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_deadline_input_2')

  additonalInput3.setAttribute('id', 'edit_mailing_dates_release_input_2')


  deadlineFrame.appendChild(datesInputFieldsFrame);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput1Td);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput2Td);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput3Td);

  additonalInput1Td.appendChild(additonalInput1);
  additonalInput2Td.appendChild(additonalInput2);
  additonalInput3Td.appendChild(additonalInput3);
});
```

```css
#edit_mailing_dates_frame {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_body div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_body_inner {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_body_inner tr {
  border: none;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_deadline_input_2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_release_input_2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

#edit_mailing_dates_delivery_input_2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h3>Mailing Order</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Mailingorder_container">
    <div class="mailing-outer-input">
      <div class="mailing-order-button" id="createNewSeason"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="MailingSeason" id="seasonOutput">


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done, if someone wishes to have a reference in the future.

```js
let currentRow = 1;




createNewDateInputFields.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const deadlineFrame =
    document.getElementById('edit_mailing_dates_table_body');
  const datesInputFieldsFrame = document.createElement('tr');
  const additonalInput1Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput2Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput3Td = document.createElement('td');
  const additonalInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  const additonalInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  const additonalInput3 = document.createElement('input');

  datesInputFieldsFrame.setAttribute('id', 'dates_input_fields_frame');
  additonalInput1.setAttribute('id',
    'edit_mailing_dates_delivery_input_' + currentRow)

  additonalInput2.setAttribute('id',
    'edit_mailing_dates_deadline_input_' + currentRow)

  additonalInput3.setAttribute('id',
    'edit_mailing_dates_release_input_' + currentRow)


  deadlineFrame.appendChild(datesInputFieldsFrame);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput1Td);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput2Td);
  datesInputFieldsFrame.appendChild(additonalInput3Td);

  additonalInput1Td.appendChild(additonalInput1);
  additonalInput2Td.appendChild(additonalInput2);
  additonalInput3Td.appendChild(additonalInput3);

  currentRow++
});
```